# How to configure %ghost files with rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, rpmbuild, rpm-maven-plugin

When creating a rpm package using a SPEC file it is possible to configure files in the %files section which will not be included in the rpm itself but owned by it.
Typical use-case are log-files which do not exist when the rpm is created but will be created when the service / application runs.

Those files are normally marked by %ghost as "prefix" in the %files section. This way those files are deleted if the rpm is uninstalled.

How do i declare ghost files using the maven plugin?

I've already read the documentation multiple times and did not find anything on SO or my favorite internet search engine.

Is it even possible to do so using the plugin or do i have to provide a custom SPEC file to the plugin somehow?